# Cannot Deplay Private SQL Server CE Winforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce

I got some issues when trying to install the setup.exe. In the log it says 'the referenced assembly couldn't be found on the computer(HRESULT: 0x800736B3).

Stack:

```
        bei System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.GetAssemblyInformation(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity, Guid& riid)
        bei System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Store.GetAssemblyManifest(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(DefinitionIdentity subId)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(SubscriptionState subState)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionState.Validate()
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.CollectCrossGroupApplications(Uri codebaseUri, DefinitionIdentity deploymentIdentity, Boolean& identityGroupFound, Boolean& locationGroupFound, String& identityGroupProductName)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

I've set everything I think. All the dlls are copied to the output dir. I've set the application to target x86.

`app.config`:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0"  
             invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe" 
             description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact"  
             type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Is there anything wrong? Or why do I still getting this issue?

Comment: Not sure it is related to SQL CE in any way, what makes you think it is?

Comment: @ErikEJ cause since i've added SQL CE the installation fails... and i dont know where else i should look... What makes you think its not?

Comment: Then you may have included the wrong version of System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Comment: Okey i see there are different versions. But i followed your steps: copy the files from c:\programs(x86)\mssqlcompac..\private\ and add it to the references. And when i double click this reference there are two System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll one with 4.0.0.0 and the other 4.0.0.1 the older comes from C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ and the newer from my solution directory. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I think you need to share a project that reproduces the issue

Comment: Sorry I cannot share the code. But can I force visual studio to take the assembly from the project folders and not from the `c:\`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91863/discussion-between-ninjaonsafari-and-erikej).